# load more list in flutter loaded but the ui doesn't change

Tags: flutter, dart, infinite-scroll, bloc

I am trying to load data from the api and i am using a bloc pattern for state management but when i call more data and add it to the list the ui is not changing.when i made the second call for the api and add the response to the list i seems like list length that come to the ui not changing to the loading indicator the loading indicator keep spinning

the event is FetchAllProjects and The State is AllProjectsLoadedState

here is the Screen ui

```
              Flexible(
              child: Container(
                child: BlocConsumer<AllProjectsBloc, AllProjectsState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is AllProjectsLoadingState) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else if (state is AllProjectsLoadedState) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        controller: _scrollController,
                        itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.allProjectsData.length  : 
                        state.allProjectsData.length +1 ,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                          return i >= 5 ? BottomLoader() : UnitCard(
                            price: state.allProjectsData[i].price,
                            date: state.allProjectsData[i].title.en,
                            image: state.allProjectsData[i].image,
                            bathroom: state.allProjectsData[i].bathroom,
                            bedroom: state.allProjectsData[i].bedroom,
                            area: state.allProjectsData[i].area,

                            function:(){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                             (context)=>DetailedProperty()));
                            });
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (state is FilteredProjectsLoadedState) {
                      return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: state.filteredProjectsData.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              return UnitCard(
                                price: 50,
                                date: '20/5/2020',
                                bedroom: 3,
                                bathroom: 2,
                                area: 120,
                                image: 
                  
                  
             'https://www.propertyturkey.com/uploads/realestate/larg/buyukcekmece_villa_1_8.jpg',
                                function:(){
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                     (context)=>DetailedProperty()));
                                } ,
                              );
                            },
                          ));
                    } else if (state is AllProjectsError) {
                      return ErrorView(
                          errorMessage: state.error.errorMessage,
                          retryAction: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<AllProjectsBloc>(context)
                                .add(state.failedEvent);
                          });
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                 
      }
```

the bloc class

```
     class AllProjectsBloc extends Bloc<AllProjectsEvents, AllProjectsState> {
        List<Data> propertyList = List();

           AllProjectsBloc() : super(AllProjectsInitialState());

         bool _hasReachedMax(AllProjectsState state) =>
            state is AllProjectsLoadedState && state.hasReachedMax;

         @override
        Stream<AllProjectsState> mapEventToState(AllProjectsEvents event) async* {
           bool isUserConnected = await NetworkUtilities.isConnected();
            if (isUserConnected == false) {
                yield AllProjectsError(
              failedEvent: event, error: Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                return;
             }
           if (event is FetchAllProjectsData && !_hasReachedMax(state)) {
               yield* _handleFetchingAllProject(event);
                      }

                  if (event is FetchFilteredProjectsData) {
          yield* _handleFetchingFilteredProject(event);
            return;
          }
            }

         Stream<AllProjectsState> _handleFetchingAllProject(
       FetchAllProjectsData event) async* {
       if (state is AllProjectsInitialState) {
  yield AllProjectsLoadingState();
  ResponseViewModel<List<Data>> handleProjectsFetchingResponse =
      await Repository.getAllPropertiesData(1);

  propertyList = handleProjectsFetchingResponse.responseData;
  print(propertyList.length);
  if (handleProjectsFetchingResponse.isSuccess) {
    yield AllProjectsLoadedState(
      allProjectsData: propertyList,
      hasReachedMax: false,
    );
  }
}
if (state is AllProjectsLoadedState) {
  ResponseViewModel<List<Data>> handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse =
      await Repository.getAllPropertiesData(2);
  List<Data> tempList = handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse.responseData;
  propertyList.addAll(tempList);

  if (handleProjectsFetchingMoreResponse.isSuccess) {
    yield AllProjectsLoadedState(
        allProjectsData: propertyList, hasReachedMax: true);
    print(propertyList.length);
  }
}
return;
   }

          Stream<AllProjectsState> _handleFetchingFilteredProject(
         FetchFilteredProjectsData event) async* {
        yield AllProjectsLoadingState();

ResponseViewModel<List<Data>> handleProjectsFetchingResponse =
    await Repository.getAllPropertiesData(1);
if (handleProjectsFetchingResponse.isSuccess) {
  propertyList = handleProjectsFetchingResponse.responseData;
  yield FilteredProjectsLoadedState(propertyList);
  return;
} else {
  yield AllProjectsError(
      failedEvent: event,
      error: handleProjectsFetchingResponse.errorViewModel);
  return;
}
```

}
}

event class

```
     class AllProjectsEvents extends Equatable {}


      class FetchAllProjectsData extends AllProjectsEvents {}
     class FetchFilteredProjectsData extends AllProjectsEvents {}
```

state class

```
                     class AllProjectsLoadedState extends AllProjectsState {

                final  List<Data>  allProjectsData;
                 final bool hasReachedMax ;

             AllProjectsLoadedState({this.allProjectsData , this.hasReachedMax}) : 
       super([allProjectsData , hasReachedMax]);

           AllProjectsLoadedState copyWith ({List<Data> allProjectsData , bool hasReachedMax }){
      return AllProjectsLoadedState(
        allProjectsData: allProjectsData ?? this.allProjectsData ,
        hasReachedMax:hasReachedMax ?? this.hasReachedMax
           );
    }

    }
```

Comment: what's the output of `print(propertyList.length);`?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the bloc consumer was not listen to the instance of the bloc that create the scrolling event .